# how i could fix this wrong in algoritimo quicksort

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

well, I have been doing a program where I need to sort words, a array String. I am using the Algorithm Quick Sort and it works nice when I sort for the first time. But when I try to sort the self array when already ordered it throws a error **java.lang.StackOverflowError**.

here is the Algorithm.

```
protected String[] ordenar(String[] array) {
       return executeQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    private String[] executeQuickSort(String[] array, int inicio, int fim){
        if(inicio < fim)
        {
            int posicaoPivo = partition(array, inicio, fim);
            if (posicaoPivo == fim) {
                posicaoPivo--;
            }
            executeQuickSort(array, inicio, posicaoPivo);
            executeQuickSort(array, posicaoPivo + 1, fim); 
        }
        return array;
    }

    private int partition(String[] array, int inicio, int fim) {
        String pivo = array[inicio];
        int i = inicio - 1 ;
        int j = fim + 1 ;

        while (true) 
        {
            i++;
            while ( i < fim && array[i].compareTo(pivo) < 0)
                i++;
                j--;
            while (j > inicio && array[j].compareTo(pivo) > 0)
                j--;

            if (i < j)
                swap(array, i, j);
            else
                return j;
        }
    }
    private void swap(String[] array, int i, int j) {
        String temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
```

I found something like mv java is using large memory and then throws a error. Some says that I need to increase the memory for this process, but would I have any other option in code line? and if I make this changes, will it work in all the pc's where i run this program?

Comment: Please add a test case running into the SOE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your partition looks odd, try this one

```
private int partition(String[] array, int inicio, int fim) {
    String pivo = array[(inicio + fim) / 2];
    int i = inicio;
    int j = fim;

    while (true) {
        while (array[i].compareTo(pivo) < 0) {
            i++;
        }
        while (array[j].compareTo(pivo) > 0) {
            j--;
        }

        if (i < j) {
            swap(array, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        } else {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your partition method need improvement. Instead of while(true),you can use while(pointL < pointR),it will reduce problem space. if you need to understand quick sort see this [example](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ddd/cis3020/summer-97/lectures/lec17/sld003.htm) .

```
     private int partition(int left,int right,String[] array){

        int pointL = left-1;
        int pointR = right;
        String[] a = array;
        // normally pivot is selected as middle elements..
        // if pivot is median of array performance going to high
        String pivot = a[left+(left+right)/2];
        while(pointL < pointR){
                while(a[++pointL].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
                while(pointR> 0 && a[--pointR].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
            if(pointL >= pointR){
                break;
            }else{
                a = swap(pointL, pointR, a);
            }
        }
        a = swap(pointL, right, a);
        return pointL;
    }

    public String[] swap(int pointL, int pointR, String[] a){
        String tmp = a[pointL];
        a[pointL] = a[pointR];
        a[pointR] = tmp;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Don't post code containing bugs.